# Div Traversing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know that, when I click on next button than `id="upper1"` become `id="upper2"` and `id="upper2"` become `id="upper3"` and `id="upper3"` become `id="upper1"` and so on.

> Jquery

$('#next').click(function() {

```
var $dives = $('div');

var total_div = $sel.length;


for (var i = 1; i <= total_div; i++) {
$dives.eq(i).attr('id', $dives.eq(i + 1).attr('id'));
}


});
```

> CSS

```
#upper1{
    background-color:red; 
}

#upper2{
    background-color:yellow; 
}

#upper3{
    background-color:orange; 
}
```

> HTML

```
    <div id="upper1">9</div>
    <div id="upper2">8</div>
    <div id="upper3">7</div>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: You forgot to add your javascript/jquery code.

Comment: Explain your question properly!

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Swapping IDs is rarely a good solution

Comment: There appears to be missing JavaScript code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort was shown

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response, and sorry for that I will not clear my question properly because it's first time I'm using this website and now I get my answer. Thanks to @Temani Afif who pick the point.
Now I wanna just close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like this that may work with any number of element with any IDs:

```js
$('#next').click(function() {
  let $sel = $('.container > div')
  let l = $sel.length;
  let last = $sel.eq(l - 1).attr('id');
  for (let i = l - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    $sel.eq(i).attr('id', $sel.eq(i - 1).attr('id'));
  }
  $sel.eq(0).attr('id', last);
})
```

```css
#upper1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#upper2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#upper3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="upper1">9</div>
  <div id="upper2">8</div>
  <div id="upper3">7</div>
</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thanks It's working Perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you may use:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
  var i1 = $("#upper1");
  var i2 = $("#upper2");
  var i3 = $("#upper3");
  i1.attr("id", "upper2");
  i2.attr("id", "upper3");
  i3.attr("id", "upper1");
});
```

You will need to put the code inside a block that waits for the page to load like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  <code here>
});
```

The use of `attr` allows to set a new `id` to each of the former id´s. Check the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hu412bm4/1/).

Also, as noted by other people, this would be better done by having fixed id´s and changing classes that defined the attributes to rotate.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, It's working !!

Answer (score 0):

Is changing the ids themselves really the goal or rather swapping the elements? (with contents)

```js
$('#next').click(function(){
 $("#container").children().last().prependTo("#container");
})
```

```css
#upper1{
    background-color:red; 
}

#upper2{
    background-color:yellow; 
}

#upper3{
    background-color:orange; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="upper1">9</div>
  <div id="upper2">8</div>
  <div id="upper3">7</div>
</div>

    <button id="next">Next</button>
```

Or if the goal is switching the colours and not the elements themselves, it can be done with classes instead of swapping the ids:

```js
$('#next').click(function(){ 
  $("[class^=upper]").each(function(){
    this.className = "upper" + (((this.className.substring(5) + 1) % 3)+1);    
  });
})
```

```css
.upper1{
    background-color:red; 
}

.upper2{
    background-color:yellow; 
}

.upper3{
    background-color:orange; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upper1">9</div>
<div class="upper2">8</div>
<div class="upper3">7</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you actually want to shuffle the divs not replace ids.

```
let divs = $(yourDivSelector);
divs.first().prepend(divs.last());
```

This code would move the last to the top and thereby move the rest down one step.